# Loading model from checkpoint is not working

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I trained a vanilla vae which I modified from [this repository](https://github.com/AntixK/PyTorch-VAE). When I try and use the trained model I am unable to load the weights using `load_from_checkpoint`. It seems there is a mismatch between my checkpoint object and my `lightningModule` object.

I have setup an experiment (`VAEXperiment`) using `pytorch-lightning LightningModule`. I try to load the weights into the network with:

```
#building a new model
model = VanillaVAE(**config['model_params'])
model.build_layers()

#loading the weights
experiment = VAEXperiment(model, config['exp_params'])
experiment.load_from_checkpoint(path_to_checkpoint, config['exp_params'])
```

I also tried:

```
checkpoint = torch.load(path_to_checkpoint, map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage)
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
```

But I get an error
`Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "model.encoder.0.0.weight", "model.encoder.0.0.bias"`...

I also followed the issue on
https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/924
https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/2798

Why I am I getting this error? Is it because of the encoder and decoder modules in my model? Based on the issues log on git it seems that the error resolved. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem with the latter case is that `VanillaVAE.model.encoder` doesn't exist. But `VanillaVAE.encoder` does. Have you tried `experiment.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])`?

Comment: Thank you Roman. That is the correct answer. Can't believe I didn't figure it out.

Comment: Why is the first approach (`experiment.load_from_checkpoint`) failing? Actually it is failing for me as well in my code. However, the second approach is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting the answer from comments:

```py
experiment.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
```